# How can I execute a specific feature file before the execution of remaining feature files in goDog?

Tags: go, bdd, gherkin

I have a few data setup before implementing the remaining test cases. I have grouped all the data setup required to be executed before the execution of test cases in a single feature file.

How can I make sure that this data setup feature file is executed before executing any other feature file in goDog framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your question, you're looking for a way to run some setup instructions prior to running your feature/scenario's. The problem is that scenario's and features are, by design, isolated. The way to ensure that something is executed prior to the scenario running is by defining a `Background` section. AFAIK you can't apply the same background across features. Scenario's are grouped per feature, and each feature can specify a `Background` that is executed before each scenario. I'd just copy-paste your setup stuff everywhere you need it:

```
Background:
  Given I have the base data:
    | User | Status   | other fields |
    | Foo  | Active   | ...          |
    | Bar  | Disabled | ...          |
```

If there's a ton of steps involved in your setup, you can define a single step that you expand to run all the *"background"* steps like so:

```
Scenario: test something
Given my test setup runs
```

Then implement the `my test setup runs` like so:

```
s.Step(`^my test setup runs$`, func() godog.Steps {
    return godog.Steps{
                   "user test data is loaded", 
                   "other things are set up",
                   "additional data is updated",
                   "update existing records",
                   "setup was successful",
            }
})
```

That ought to work.

Of course, to avoid having to start each scenario with that `Given my test setup runs`, you can just start each feature file with:

```
Background:
   Given my test setup runs
```

That will ensure the setup is performed before each scenario. The upshot will be: 2 additional lines at the start of each feature file, and you're all set to go.

Comment: The case you have mentioned here uses Background, and I have read we should try and keep it as small as possible. I have a feature file that has many steps to be executed before any test case to be executed. My requirement is that I need to load data from that file before any other feature file is executed. I looked over for answers and found out that cucumber executes files in alphabetical order, so I can name that file so that it is always executed first. But with this approach I am not sure to proceed. Is there any other way?

Comment: @Shubham It executes in alphabetical order, but it doesn't maintain state between scenario's, so you'll have to set up the state you need each time. That's exactly why background exists. If you're setting up too much state, then perhaps the problem is more to do with what you're trying to test, I'm afraid. Cucumber is great at integration testing, but to test more thorough end-to-end scenario's, there might be better tools, or you might want to use the background to just load in a DB for a base-state

Comment: Thanks for clarifying my doubts about file naming. I will look to implement it using Background only.